# Azure: find if storage is general purpose or blob storage using storage API

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to determine whether a storage account is blob storage or general purpose storage using the Azure storage Java API

Answer (score -1):

According to the Azure Storage REST API [`Create Storage Account`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/srp_json_create_storage_account#request-body-http-200-version-2016-01-01-and-later)(only version 2016-01-01 and later), you can see a parameter `kind` which determine what kind of storage account (`Storage` or `BlobStorage`) will be created in the request body.

For using Azure Storage Java API, there is an enum class [`Kind`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/Kind.html) which includes the two kinds of storage account, you can select the one of you want via two interfaces ([`WithGeneralPurposeAccountKind`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/StorageAccount.DefinitionStages.WithGeneralPurposeAccountKind.html#withGeneralPurposeAccountKind--) and [`WithBlobStorageAccountKind`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/StorageAccount.DefinitionStages.WithBlobStorageAccountKind.html#withBlobStorageAccountKind--)) of `StorageAccount.DefinitionStages` interface.

Here are the usual usages of them.

1. Create a default kind storage account via `define` method, see the completed sample code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/samples/ManageStorageAccount.java#L46).

   ```
   StorageAccount storageAccount = azure.storageAccounts().define(storageAccountName)
                   .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
                   .withNewResourceGroup(rgName)
                   .create();
   ```

   According to the source code of [`define`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/ebcb486b6f4cb581918a38cb02a3bf48df263662/azure-mgmt-storage/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/storage/implementation/StorageAccountsImpl.java#L56) method, the default kind of storage account is `Storage` via `WithGeneralPurposeAccountKind`.
2. Create a storage account of `BlobStorage` kind.

   ```
   StorageAccount storageAccount = azure.storageAccounts().define(storageAccountName)
                       .withBlobStorageAccountKind() // Set the kind as `BlobStorage`
                       .withRegion(Region.US_EAST)
                       .withNewResourceGroup(rgName)
                       .create();
   ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The OP was asking how to get the kind of an existing storage account, not how to create a new account of a specific type.